# javascript indexof within jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I have some code here that looks for every mention of "[code]" and turns it into `<code>` but I only want to do this within a specific jquery element...

```
      function formattxt(text){
        if (text == '') return '';

        var start = text.indexOf('[code]');
        var end = text.indexOf('[/code]', start);

...
```

How would I do that?

I'm looking for something simple like the following:

```
var start = $("#element").text.indexOf('[code]');
var end =  $("#element").text.indexOf('[/code]', start);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To Enable the replacement, you'd better use `replace`:

```
function replaceTag (text) {
  $('#element').text().replace('[' + text + ']', '<' + text + '>')
}
```

If you want ot use `indexOf`, use the following as mentioned by @zzzzBov

```
$('#element').text().indexOf('[code]');
```

**Be careful** with `indexOf`, as it is not supported by IE6-8, You need to include [thid code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to function in all browsers.

Comment: I'm passing 'text' through as a variable so I want to look at the 'text' but only the 'text' within $("#example");

Answer (score 5):

Read [the jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/):

```
$('#element').text().indexOf('[code]');
```

Comment: or `val()` if it's an input, but yeah, this.

Comment: I'm passing 'text' through as a variable so I want to look at the 'text' but only the 'text' within $("#example");